# Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature

Tags: linux, fedora, android, emulators

I was able to get a remote viewer set up on my mac to remote view a Fedora server desktop. I run `~/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` to launch Android Studio. I open AVD manager and try to boot up an emulator, but I get message

> AVD is allready runing ...

[image]

and when I try to boot emulator `device1` from command line

```
emulator -avd device1
```

I get message

> emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.
>   Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.

so overwhelming evidence is that `device1` emulator is already running, and yet when I run command `adb devices` I get messages

> List of devices attached

indicating no running devices ... so whats up?

**edit**

I delete all *.lock files, and press play; the dialog did not appear, however, the emulator also did not appear, but when I ran `adb devices`, no devices were shown, and then I pressed play again, I got the same dialog.

**edit**

```
I create new device and booted from command line and got

$ emulator -avd device3
Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:66: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))


failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not make GLES 2.x context current!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, I had to change to values in the config file in the emu directory

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193692/how-to-fix-emulator-warning-qxcbintegration-cannot-create-platform-opengl-c